# Whole website no-index, no-follow

Tags: magento2, seo, staging, no-index, no-follow

I am using Magento 2, and I have staging server, I don't want any crawler or bots to index my staging server.

So, I need whole website to be no-index, no follow. Is it possible in Magento?

Comment: add this in layout 
`<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to configuration

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Edit **Global configuration**

In **Search Engine Robots** tab, you can set **Default Robots** value to **"Noindex, Nofollow"**

In addition, create file `robots.txt` in `root` and `pub/` directory. File content would be:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thanks Shoaib Munir

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to remove the tag from the code as this is a back-end setting. You can change the setting by logging in to your back-office then go to

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

then click on the correct storeview. Under the tab `Search Engine Robots` you find the option

Comment: Thanks Rathod..

Comment: working or not ?

Comment: Yes working, but adding robots.txt is also a good solution. I cannot mark two answer correct, otherwise I would do that. +1

Comment: Good answer though. +1